# Trouble using the OR operator in a jQuery if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements

My aim is to check a given ingredient for different attributes with an list of OR statements, but it returns an unexpected || error.

```
$(".ingredient.clicked").each(function() {
  if (typeof $(this).attr("noAddedSugar") != "undefined") 
      || (typeof $(this).attr("vegan") != "undefined") 
      || (typeof $(this).attr("glutenfree") != "undefined")  
  {
    $('#proba').text("Proba");
  } else {
    $('#proba').text("");
    return false;
  }  
});
```

It works when I add and modify the variables individually, does not when I use OR. Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not valid JS. Check your console for errors.

Comment: you unclosed the ")" condition , typeof $(this).attr("noAddedSugar") != "undefined") need to be open first

Comment: if-syntax is `if(expression)` not `if (expression) || (expression)` so you need `if ((expression) || (expression))`

Comment: I rolled back your edit because it invalidated all existing answers. Please don't make destructive edits that invalidate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   if (typeof $(this).attr("noAddedSugar") != "undefined") || (typeof $(this).attr("vegan") != "undefined") || (typeof $(this).attr("glutenfree") != "undefined")
```

should be

```
if( (typeof $(this).attr("noAddedSugar") != "undefined") || (typeof $(this).attr("vegan") != "undefined") || (typeof $(this).attr("glutenfree") != "undefined")  )
```

Comment: Quick question regarding the answer. If I use this code - if( (typeof $(this).attr("vegan") != "undefined") || (typeof $(this).attr("glutenfree") != "undefined") || (typeof $(this).attr("vegetarian") != "undefined") ) {
  
  $('#diettext').text("ALAPSZÓSZ NÉLKÜL KÉRD!"); 
  
}

else {
  
  $('#diettext').text("");
  $('#diettext').fadeTo( 1000, 0 );
  
}    
The IF part of the statement works great, but not matter what I do, I can't get the else part to function. Would you mind looking at it? https://codepen.io/Pbalazs89/full/LOjqQM

Answer (score 2):

Your if logic needs to be fully enclosed in a separate set of parentheses:

```
 if ((typeof $(this).attr("noAddedSugar") != "undefined") || (typeof $(this).attr("vegan") != "undefined") || (typeof $(this).attr("glutenfree") != "undefined"))
```

The way it is now, it ends after the first `!="undefined")`

The inner parentheses around each condition are not necessary, so you can simplify it a bit more with:

```
if( typeof $(this).attr("noAddedSugar") != "undefined" || typeof $(this).attr("vegan") != "undefined" || typeof $(this).attr("glutenfree") != "undefined" )
```